# How to extract data from sqldb and display it on alertbody of UILocalnotification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

Hi i am trying to display data from db on `UILocalNotification`. I have list of items in my db each item has descriptions. I want to display the description in `UILocalNotification`. When I tap on item, an `UILocalNotification` should appear with descriptions on it. When I tap on another item its descriptions should appear on `alerview`.

I am retrieving data from db. I don't know how to put it to `UILocalNotification's` alert body.

```
didSelectedListID = [[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"RemedyID"]intValue];
```

`didSelectedListID` contains id number for that particular List .

```
NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:01];
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if(notifyAlarm)
{
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = [];
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

Comment: Is the problem in getting the values from database or in scheduling & populating the UILocalNotification?

Comment: the values should be fetched from database and schedule , populate in the UILocalNotification